# How come this python pandas dataframe for loop only fills the first row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spotipy

I'm working with Spotify's Spotipy library, and trying to build a pandas dataframe of audio features from Spotify's API.

I'm going about this in what I feel is probably a very inefficient (slow) way, but as of now I've got a dataframe `pddf`, and I want to access the API to pull audio features for specific tracks using the track's URI (in one of the columns).

As of now, I've got this code...

```
for i in pddf.index:
    track = df.loc[i, 'track.uri']
    track = re.findall('(?<=track:).*$', track)
    features = sp.audio_features(tracks=track)
    audio_features = pd.DataFrame(features)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date = '%d/%d/%d' % (now.month, now.day, now.year)
    audio_features['Date'] = date
    audio_features = audio_features[
        ['Date', 'acousticness', 'analysis_url', 'danceability', 'duration_ms', 'energy', 'id',
         'instrumentalness', 'key', 'liveness', 'loudness', 'mode', 'speechiness', 'tempo', 'time_signature',
         'track_href', 'type', 'uri', 'valence']]
    pddf = pd.concat([audio_features, pddf], axis=1)
```

And it returns this:

```
Date    acousticness    analysis_url    danceability    duration_ms energy  id  instrumentalness    key liveness    loudness    mode    speechiness tempo   time_signature  track_href  type    uri valence Date    acousticness    analysis_url    danceability    duration_ms energy  id  instrumentalness    key liveness    loudness    mode    speechiness tempo   time_signature  track_href  type    uri valence Date    acousticness    analysis_url    danceability    duration_ms energy  id  instrumentalness    key liveness    loudness    mode    speechiness tempo   time_signature  track_href  type    uri valence Date    acousticness    analysis_url    danceability    duration_ms energy  id  instrumentalness    key liveness    loudness    mode    speechiness tempo   time_signature  track_href  type    uri valence Date    acousticness    analysis_url    danceability    duration_ms energy  id  instrumentalness    key liveness    loudness    mode    speechiness tempo   time_signature  track_href  type    uri valence played_at   context.external_urls.spotify   context.href    context.type    context.uri track.album.album_type  track.album.artists track.album.available_markets   track.album.external_urls.spotify   track.album.href    track.album.id  track.album.images  track.album.name    track.album.release_date    track.album.release_date_precision  track.album.total_tracks    track.album.type    track.album.uri track.artists   track.available_markets track.disc_number   track.duration_ms   track.explicit  track.external_ids.isrc track.external_urls.spotify track.href  track.id    track.is_local  track.name  track.popularity    track.preview_url   track.track_number  track.type  track.uri
0   3/10/20 0.523   https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/2vWxvpycD0ELvOJr6g4pQt    0.65    155960  0.495   2vWxvpycD0ELvOJr6g4pQt  0.723   0   0.123   -6.385  0   0.0451  80.032  4   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2vWxvpycD0ELvOJr6g4pQt    audio_features  spotify:track:2vWxvpycD0ELvOJr6g4pQt    0.394   3/10/20 0.036   https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/33pDmPx2pkJ7JCAQpRDQ9B    0.681   298027  0.621   33pDmPx2pkJ7JCAQpRDQ9B  0.00555 1   0.138   -10.024 1   0.34    135.538 4   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/33pDmPx2pkJ7JCAQpRDQ9B    audio_features  spotify:track:33pDmPx2pkJ7JCAQpRDQ9B    0.428   3/10/20 0.00677 https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/3bcVlSWtjktTZAczUbfzlG    0.771   268080  0.786   3bcVlSWtjktTZAczUbfzlG  0.901   10  0.705   -7.324  0   0.0648  119.961 4   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/3bcVlSWtjktTZAczUbfzlG    audio_features  spotify:track:3bcVlSWtjktTZAczUbfzlG    0.19    3/10/20 0.0323  https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/2b4SSorCTQ2VzmllaeWuuT    0.824   227707  0.396   2b4SSorCTQ2VzmllaeWuuT  0.00289 2   0.108   -9.663  1   0.332   118.053 4   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2b4SSorCTQ2VzmllaeWuuT    audio_features  spotify:track:2b4SSorCTQ2VzmllaeWuuT    0.252   3/10/20 0.122   https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/4YcHuaXJb6dnGWkJzmCcwu    0.792   277960  0.478   4YcHuaXJb6dnGWkJzmCcwu  0.00157 6   0.519   -10.626 1   0.434   119.979 4   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4YcHuaXJb6dnGWkJzmCcwu    audio_features  spotify:track:4YcHuaXJb6dnGWkJzmCcwu    0.134   2020-03-10T23:51:04.493Z    https://open.spotify.com/album/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    album   spotify:album:1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    album   [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'id': '6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'name': 'KAYTRANADA', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}] ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    https://open.spotify.com/album/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z  [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27342c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e0242c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000485142c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 64}]    99.90%  5/6/16  day 15  album   spotify:album:1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'id': '6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'name': 'KAYTRANADA', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/3sJQwG0SsGRyv5C5kh4o9a'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3sJQwG0SsGRyv5C5kh4o9a', 'id': '3sJQwG0SsGRyv5C5kh4o9a', 'name': 'Shay Lia', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:3sJQwG0SsGRyv5C5kh4o9a'}]    ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    1   277960  FALSE   GBBKS1600026    https://open.spotify.com/track/4YcHuaXJb6dnGWkJzmCcwu   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4YcHuaXJb6dnGWkJzmCcwu    4YcHuaXJb6dnGWkJzmCcwu  FALSE   LEAVE ME ALONE  50  https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/d78a4e357db1aa818cc1596f0b200e3dbc5f3425?cid=a98a5116ec7149be9fbec4e5ff8afc18 14  track   spotify:track:4YcHuaXJb6dnGWkJzmCcwu
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               2020-03-10T23:43:33.975Z    https://open.spotify.com/album/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    album   spotify:album:1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    album   [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'id': '6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'name': 'KAYTRANADA', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}] ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    https://open.spotify.com/album/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z  [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27342c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e0242c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000485142c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 64}]    99.90%  5/6/16  day 15  album   spotify:album:1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'id': '6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'name': 'KAYTRANADA', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/3jk39CGeaaSO3FPKNx1RUx'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3jk39CGeaaSO3FPKNx1RUx', 'id': '3jk39CGeaaSO3FPKNx1RUx', 'name': 'Syd', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:3jk39CGeaaSO3FPKNx1RUx'}] ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    1   227706  FALSE   GBBKS1600023    https://open.spotify.com/track/2b4SSorCTQ2VzmllaeWuuT   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2b4SSorCTQ2VzmllaeWuuT    2b4SSorCTQ2VzmllaeWuuT  FALSE   YOU'RE THE ONE  64  https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/ba855fc4a56715e3110abdc7c01f9c330e57d6a8?cid=a98a5116ec7149be9fbec4e5ff8afc18 11  track   spotify:track:2b4SSorCTQ2VzmllaeWuuT
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               2020-03-10T23:39:46.318Z    https://open.spotify.com/album/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    album   spotify:album:1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    album   [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'id': '6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'name': 'KAYTRANADA', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}] ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    https://open.spotify.com/album/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z  [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27342c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e0242c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000485142c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 64}]    99.90%  5/6/16  day 15  album   spotify:album:1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'id': '6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'name': 'KAYTRANADA', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}] ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    1   268080  FALSE   GBBKS1600022    https://open.spotify.com/track/3bcVlSWtjktTZAczUbfzlG   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/3bcVlSWtjktTZAczUbfzlG    3bcVlSWtjktTZAczUbfzlG  FALSE   BREAKDANCE LESSON N.1   45  https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/c84c2e71c8914a3b774831cb1bf0052e9dabcb41?cid=a98a5116ec7149be9fbec4e5ff8afc18 10  track   spotify:track:3bcVlSWtjktTZAczUbfzlG
3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               2020-03-10T23:33:41.044Z    https://open.spotify.com/album/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    album   spotify:album:1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    album   [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'id': '6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'name': 'KAYTRANADA', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}] ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    https://open.spotify.com/album/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z  [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27342c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e0242c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000485142c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 64}]    99.90%  5/6/16  day 15  album   spotify:album:1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'id': '6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'name': 'KAYTRANADA', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/3jK9MiCrA42lLAdMGUZpwa'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3jK9MiCrA42lLAdMGUZpwa', 'id': '3jK9MiCrA42lLAdMGUZpwa', 'name': 'Anderson .Paak', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:3jK9MiCrA42lLAdMGUZpwa'}]  ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    1   298026  TRUE    GBBKS1600021    https://open.spotify.com/track/33pDmPx2pkJ7JCAQpRDQ9B   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/33pDmPx2pkJ7JCAQpRDQ9B    33pDmPx2pkJ7JCAQpRDQ9B  FALSE   GLOWED UP   62  https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/8664d17376b7057278eab899090453599d8b1d64?cid=a98a5116ec7149be9fbec4e5ff8afc18 9   track   spotify:track:33pDmPx2pkJ7JCAQpRDQ9B
4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               2020-03-10T23:27:58.985Z    https://open.spotify.com/album/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    album   spotify:album:1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    album   [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'id': '6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'name': 'KAYTRANADA', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}] ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    https://open.spotify.com/album/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z  [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27342c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e0242c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000485142c18fe458181bc13d08070a', 'width': 64}]    99.90%  5/6/16  day 15  album   spotify:album:1dZZh7PvVgce1DDsDPzy8Z    [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'id': '6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu', 'name': 'KAYTRANADA', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6qgnBH6iDM91ipVXv28OMu'}, {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/65dGLGjkw3UbddUg2GKQoZ'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/65dGLGjkw3UbddUg2GKQoZ', 'id': '65dGLGjkw3UbddUg2GKQoZ', 'name': 'BADBADNOTGOOD', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:65dGLGjkw3UbddUg2GKQoZ'}]   ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    1   155960  FALSE   GBBKS1600017    https://open.spotify.com/track/2vWxvpycD0ELvOJr6g4pQt   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2vWxvpycD0ELvOJr6g4pQt    2vWxvpycD0ELvOJr6g4pQt  FALSE   WEIGHT OFF  57  https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/49c10722ab7f493069a2f1c189b52374756bc1b0?cid=a98a5116ec7149be9fbec4e5ff8afc18 6   track   spotify:track:2vWxvpycD0ELvOJr6g4pQt
```

with all of the data I want to fill in each row instead in **just** the first row, with multiple duplicate columns...

Any idea how to fix this? It has had me stumped...also, advice on making it more efficient would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last row

```
pddf = pd.concat([audio_features, pddf], axis=0)
```

Comment: ...crap. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Any idea why it would still be pasting them on separate lines, however? Now it doesn't seem to be placing new data next to the proper rows D:

Comment: @moolz after fix this, you can check the data format , I think there is some row or item miss in the api output